# Kendo Grid column with Kendo Menu template

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, web, kendo-ui

I have a kendo grid with the following columns:

```js
var columns = [
    {title: "row", template: "#= gridRowCounter++ #"},
    {field: "FName", title: "Name"},
    {field: "LName", title: "Family"},
    {title: "Actions", template: 
            '<ul id="menu#=gridRowCounter-1#" >'+  
                '<li>Action<ul>'+  
                    '<li><span class="k-link" onclick="edit()">Edit</span></li>'+  
                    '<li><span class="k-link" onclick="delete()">Delete</span></li>'+  
                '</ul></li>'+  
            '</ul>'}
    ];
```

---

I generate and initialize the grid first:

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource : myDS,
    columns : columns,
    change: function() {
        var menus = $("ul[id*='menu']");
        for(var i = 0; i < menus.length; i++){  
            $(menus[i]).kendoMenu({
                direction: "right",
                animation: { open: { effects: "slideIn:right" } }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and then initialize the menus by selecting a row.
It works and the menus are made but the sub menus are opened under the grid bounds and not appear.
I want you help me get the menus top of all elements.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grid table cells have an overflow:hidden style applied by default. You can override it with

```css
.k-grid tr td
{
     overflow:visible;
}
```