# Kendo Grid column template de-initialized after canceling popup edit window

Tags: javascript, html, web, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid that reads data from external services using Kendo DataSource, and I have the last column defined by a template that creates a Kendo Menu for each row of the grid (exactly like [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781929/kendo-grid-column-with-kendo-menu-template)).

Problem however is, I have the editable attribute set to "popup" mode. So when I click "Edit" (and then the popup window opens), if I hit "Cancel", the Kendo Menu at that very row that I edited gets de-initialized and looks like a normal ul/li menu without a style.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess. The row is rerendered by the kendo grid, so your menu is now again displayed as plain HTML, and you have to call kendoMenu() again...

Try to cache the menu somewhere else, and append it to each row on mouseenter for example. So you are not depended on the grid refreshing and losing your menus.